# Get KotlinNullPointerException when open initial fragment

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, nullpointerexception

Get KotlinNullPointerException when open initial fragment when init my `uid`:

```
fun setInitialData() {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        uid = firebaseUser!!.uid
```

But if I replace initialization on `firebaseUser?.uid` database data will not load immediately.
So understand this the right approach?
Also i understand how extra the decision to do some pause before data is loaded?

Comment: @JeelVankhede ok, but as i say, if i use `firebaseUser?.uid`, I have a problem with uploading data.

Comment: can you post the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation regarding FirebaseUser's [getCurrentUser()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#getCurrentUser()) method:

> Returns the currently signed-in FirebaseUser or **null** if there is none.

And to answer your question:

> So understand this the right approach?

No, you need to always use `getCurrentUser() != null` to check if a user is signed in or not.

> Also i understand how extra the decision to do some pause before data is loaded?

There is no need to pause something in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase auth can't be initialized when an activity or a fragment is created as it takes time to become responsive. Try to pass it in a button click or anywhere other than oncreate.

Comment: i tried to init my firebase in `onViewCreated`. In method : `setInitialData()`.
U can check full code here: https://gist.github.com/mnewlive/56c4a84eb3ef22f930779e49c710fc4a